# Parsing html with lxml: error in decoding

Tags: python, lxml, decode

http://www.findmice.org/repository

```
$ file /tmp/repository.html
/tmp/repository.html: HTML document text, ISO-8859 text
```

I am trying to parse the above file by the following python code.

```
from lxml import html
doc = html.parse(sys.stdin, parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding='iso-8859-1'))
```

But I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../imsrrepo.py", line 14, in <module>
    doc = html.parse(sys.stdin, parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding='iso-8859-1'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 939, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3467, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1860, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1880, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1775, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1187, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 707, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 318, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 370, in lxml.etree._FileReaderContext.copyToBuffer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 3597: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Is `/tmp/repository.html` just the saved source code of the url?

Comment: Yes. It is the case.

Comment: Can you read the file directly from the url, or do you need to save it first?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file, "r", encoding="iso-8859-1") as html_file:
  doc = html.parse(html_file)
```

I think lxml has never said that `lxml.html.parse` support encoding method. Maybe hidden in the source code, but they never state it in the documentation. It is also possible lxml Http parser cannot handle the “iso-8859-1” or the encoding stated in META doesn’t match the real encoding.

May be someone can provide you better explanation, but as far as I know, we should read it with proper encoding or using BeautifulSoup. This is stated in the doc,

> However, note that the most common problem with web pages is the lack
>   of (or the existence of incorrect) encoding declarations. It is
>   therefore often sufficient to only use the encoding detection of
>   BeautifulSoup, called UnicodeDammit, and to leave the rest to lxml's
>   own HTML parser, which is several times faster.

Comment: How to deal with `sys.stdin`. I got this errro `    with open(sys.stdin, "r", encoding="iso-8859-1") as html_file:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper`